# How to create an inapp tutorial?

Tags: android

I want to create a tutorial in my app that shows the user how to use it. For example there is some kind of message on the screen that points at a button and the message tells the user what the button does. This means that I have to be able to place the message freely on the screen. I don't want to use toasts because the disappear too fast.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the [ShowcaseView Library](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView).

[image: ShowcaseView sample image]

It does basically everything your asking for and as an additional plus it's also used by *Google*. (Not the library itself but the presentation style of the "tutorial"). There's also a Sample application in the [Play Store (click)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.espian.showcaseview.sample&hl=de).

Usage of the library is pretty simple, you just define the `View` which you want to highlight and the title/text like this:

```
ViewTarget target = new ViewTarget(R.id.viewToHighlight, this);
new ShowcaseView.Builder(this, true)
     .setTarget(target)
     .setContentTitle("TITLE")
     .setContentText("MESSAGE")
     .hideOnTouchOutside()
     .build();
```